# Find inverse of $[-2] \bmod 5$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given the equation:
$$42x\equiv 1\pmod 5$$
I have determined the class $[-2]_{5}$ as $x$ solution of the given equation.
Now I have to find the inverse of $x$ (i.e. $x^{-1}=[-2]_5^{-1}$ ). As far as I know, the $x=[-2]_5$ first found is just $[42]_5^{-1}$, and so the inverse of inverse (i.e. $([42]_5^{-1})^{-1}$) is just $42$ again, so $[42]_5=[-2]_5=[x]_5^{-1}$

Am I wrong=

Comment: $-2 \equiv 3$, so you're just looking for the multiplicative inverse of $3$? It's $2$, since $3 \cdot 2 = 6 \equiv 1(mod 5)$

Comment: That $42 \cdot (-2) \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ implies that $[42]_5 = [2]_5$ is the inverse of $[-2]_5$.

Comment: @TheChaz : If you write 3\cdot2=6\equiv1\pmod 5 in $\TeX$, it looks like this: $3\cdot2=6\equiv1\pmod 5$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Noted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrong in saying that $[42]_5=[-2]_5$.

You found $x$ correctly, since $[42]_5[-2]_5=[2]_5[3]_5=[6]_5=[1]_5$ , although since we are working mod 5 it is traditional to choose the representative between $0$ and $4$ so instead of $[-2]_5$ you might write $[3]_5$.  Thus $[42]_5$ (i.e. $[2]_5$) and $[3]_5$ are inverses of each other in $\mathbb{Z}/5$

Answer (score 1):

Write down the powers of $2$ modulo $5$. They are $2^0=1$, $2^1=2$, $2^2=4\equiv-1$, $2^3=8\equiv3$, and $2^4=16\equiv1$. Now all is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gauss Method and taking modulo 5: 1/42 = 1/2 = 3/6 = 3